# Zsh export ignoring quotes and backslashes

Tags: shell, environment-variables, zsh

I have a shell script (let's call it `produce.sh`) which outputs data in the following form, but does not save it to a file:

```
FOO=value
BAR=value2
ZAP=value3
```

I'd like to use these values as environment variables in a shell script. I'm currently doing this using the following shell code:

```
export $(./produce.sh)
```

This works great, except when the values to the right of the `=` contain spaces. For instance:

```
FOO=split value
```

I've tried two different approaches in `produce.sh`:

1. Wrapping the values in quotes (`FOO="split value"`)
2. Escaping whitespace with backslashes (`FOO=split\ value`)

Both of these do not work: if I inspect the environment variables, `FOO` contains `"split` in the first example and `split\` in the second.

How can I get `export` to handle this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `f` parameter expansion flag in `zsh` will split an input on newlines, so this should handle input values with whitespace:

```
export ${(f)"$(./produce.sh)"}
```

---

###### What's happening

The output from produce.sh:

- key-value pairs.
- each kv pair is on its own line.
- key is separated from the value by `=`.
- syntax is shell-like, but not exactly shell syntax, so,
- white space and some other characters special to the shell are allowed in the value.

The parts of the substitution:

- `produce.sh` : generates the key-value output, for example: `N=V1\nP=V 2\n`.
- `$(...)` : command substitution. It is replaced with the output, minus trailing newlines: `N=V1\nP=V 2`.
- `"..."` : the quotes ensure that the prior result is treated as a single term for the next step.
- `${(f)...}` : expands that single term into multiple scalar values, splitting on newlines due to the `(f)` flag. The result is effectively `'N=V1' 'P=V 2'`.
- `export` : assigns and exports each parameter, acting like `export 'N=V1' 'P=V 2'`.

---

###### Another option

The substitution below adds some other cryptic zsh-isms to create an associative array. This avoids adding arbitrary variables to the consuming shell's
environment:

```
% ./s2.sh
A=A
B=
C=C C
% typeset -A vals=("${(@s:=:)${(f)"$(./s2.sh)"}}")
% print ${vals[A]}
A
% print ${vals[C]}
C C
```

A minor tradeoff - this will not work if the value contains an equals, e.g.
`D=D=D`.

Comment: I don't fully understand the syntax, but this is what did it. Thanks!

Comment: @mattbasta : See `man zshexpn`, section _PARAMETER EXPANSION_, where the _f_  flag is described.

Comment: @mattbasta - I added an attempt at an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOO=split value
```

Does **not** set a variable to a value containing a space. It temporarily sets `FOO` to *split* and runs the command `value` in an environment where `FOO` has been set. The overall effect is similar to

```
(export FOO=split; value)
```

You can experiment with this by doing a

```
FOO=split printenv
```

which will run `printenv` and show in its output the value of `FOO`.

To set a variable to a value containing space, you need to escape the space, for instance with

```
FOO=split\ value
```

or by using quotes.

For processing this file, you could use `eval`:

```
eval export $(./produce.sh)
```

Of course you should this only if you have full control over what produce.sh is writing to stdout (i.e. don't let any tainted data sneak in), because  `eval` is a potential security hole.

Alternatively, you could modify produce.sh to already produce the `export` prefix in front of each line, and then do just a

```
eval $(./produce.sh)
```

Comment: "To set a variable to a value containing space, you need to escape the space, for instance with"

This is exactly what I described doing in my question (both with backslashes and quotes) and the result is my program showing `os.environ['FOO'] == 'split\\'` and `os.environ['FOO'] == '"split'` respectively.

Comment: @mattbasta : Extended my answer accordingly.